# Удаление дубликатов из двух массивов

Tags: c#, .net

Задача такова: у меня есть два массива `a` и `b`, в них мне нужно найти элементы встречающиеся в обоих массивах и вывести новый массив без этих элементов. Пример:

```
var a = new int[] {1, 2, 2};
var b = new int[] {2, 2};
var result = new int[] {1};
```

Задачу я уже решил, вот мой код:

```
public static int[] ArrayDiff(int[] a, int[] b)
{
var intersect = a.Intersect(b).ToArray();
a = a.Except(intersect).ToArray();
b = b.Except(intersect).ToArray();
var result = a.Union(b);
return result.ToArray();
}

public static void Main()
{
int[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int[] array_2 = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", ArrayDiff(array, array_2)));
}
```

Выводится все правильно, но есть одна ошибка, которую мне нужно обработать. Когда я не ввожу в консоль ничего, то есть оставляю массив пустым или после введенного числа ввожу более одного пробела, у меня появляется исключение:

`System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.`

Мне нужна помощь в обработке данного исключения и желательно чтобы оно было написано в методе `ArrayDiff`, так как на сайте где я решаю данную задачу, метода `Main` нет. И если что, то в главном методе `Main` я уже писал обработку этого исключения с помощью `try/cath`, но это не самый лучший вариант потому что, как я уже сказал, на сайте этой задачи у меня есть только один метод, в котором я должен написать весь код.

Comment: `try-catch` вокруг строк с ридлайнами из консоли. Касательно данного конкретного кода, исключение возникает в методе Main, и обработать его можно только в методе Main.

Comment: но можно еще так попробовать `Console.ReadLine().Split().Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()` тогда исключения при пустом вводе не будет.

Comment: `.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - устранит проблему нескольких пробелов подряд.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочий вариант

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
var rule = @"[0-9 ]";
string stringarr = "";

while (true)
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        break;

    if (Regex.IsMatch(key.KeyChar.ToString(), rule))
    {
        stringarr += key.KeyChar.ToString();
        Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
    }
}
stringarr = Regex.Replace(stringarr,@"\s+", " ");

int[] arr = stringarr.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine((string.Join(' ', arr)));
```